# batch script to exit process with error

Tags: batch-file, profile

I work for a school district and we need to remotely remove profiles.  We are using RemProf. I need the script to fail if it encounters two specific domains or a device with a specific identifier in the name.  I want it to exit with an error code.  This will let our field staff know that they have tried to run RemProf against a device that is restricted because of domain or name.  Here is what I have.  The line with `-SAD-` identifies part of a device name.  This script is not exiting if it encounters an error level of 1.  It continues with RemProf and deletes profiles. I would appreciate any guidance.

```
Reg Query HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters /v Hostname /f -SAD-
if %ERRORLEVEL%==1 exit /b 9

Reg Query HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters /v Domain /f teach.inst.schools
if %ERRORLEVEL%==1 exit /b 0

Reg Query HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters /v Domain /f admin.schools
if %ERRORLEVEL%==1 exit /b 9


Reg Query HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters /v Domain /f elem.inst.schools
if %ERRORLEVEL%==0 goto Run_RemProf

Reg Query HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters /v Domain /f sec.inst.schools
if %ERRORLEVEL%==0 goto Run_RemProf


:Run_RemProf

Rem Deleteing profiles and abandoned files

RemProf.exe /D: /EXCLUDE:Public,Default,Administrator,SOL
RemProf.exe /AD: /EXCLUDE:Public,Default,Administrator,SOL
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Reg Query HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters /v Hostname /f -SAD-` **always** returns `Hostname` value, along with appropriate `errorlevel` return value of `0` - success (or `1` - failure) **regardless of** data or pattern supplied in `/f` switch.

`reg query /?` is a bit short about using `/V` and `/F` switches together:

> ```
>   /v       Queries for a specific registry key values.
>            If omitted, all values for the key are queried.
>
>            Argument to this switch can be optional only when specified
>            along with /f switch. This specifies to search in valuenames only.
>
>   /f       Specifies the data or pattern to search for.
>            Use double quotes if a string contains spaces. Default is "*".
> ```

[Another official source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742028(v=ws.11).aspx) says about `/V` switch:

> `/v <ValueName>`  Specifies the registry value name that is to be
>   queried. If omitted, all value names for KeyName are returned.
>   `ValueName` for this parameter is **optional** if the `/f` option is
>   also used.

Optional? [Read `dictionary.com` definitions for adjective **optional**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/optional?s=t):

- common: left to one's choice; not required or mandatory;
- British: possible but not compulsory; left to personal choice.

In fact, [`ValueName` for `/V` parameter should be **omitted** if the `/f` option is also used](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/regsearch.php) (nonofficial):

> To search part of the registry, use the following syntax:
>
> ```
> REG Query HKxx\subkey [/D|/K|/V] /F "search_pattern" [/S] [/E] [/C]
> ```
>
> Use `/D` to search the data (i.e. the registry values' values), `/K`
>   to search for matching key names, `/V` to search for matching value
>   names, or none of these switches to search keys, values and data.

You can:

- check `ERRORLEVEL` from [`findstr` command](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) rather, or
- set desired *registry data* to suitable *environment variable* and then check [whether this variable contains specified substring](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html).

**Sample script** (partially commented):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "_pattern=%~1"        for demonstration purposes: first line parameter
if not defined _pattern set "_pattern=-SAD-"

    rem next `_KeyName` variable keeps `reg query` line length <80 chars
set "_KeyName=HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters"

echo(
echo `findstr` approach:
Reg Query "%_KeyName%" /v Hostname | findstr /I /C:"%_pattern%" >NUL
if errorlevel 1 (
  echo `Hostname` data DOES NOT CONTAIN specified string "%_pattern%"
) else (
  echo `Hostname` data CONTAINS specified string "%_pattern%"
)

echo(
echo `substring` approach:
    rem set `_Hostname` and `_Domain`  
for /F "tokens=1,2,*" %%G in ('
    Reg Query "%_KeyName%" ^| findstr /I /R "\<Domain\> \<Hostname\>"
                            ') do set "_%%G=%%I"
call set "_auxiliary=%%_Hostname:%_pattern%=%%"
if "%_auxiliary%"=="%_Hostname%" (
  echo `Hostname` data DOES NOT CONTAIN specified string "%_pattern%"
) else (
  echo `Hostname` data CONTAINS specified string "%_pattern%"
)
```

**Output**:

```
==> D:\bat\SO\39359057.bat -SAD-

`findstr` approach:
`Hostname` data DOES NOT CONTAIN specified string "-SAD-"

`substring` approach:
`Hostname` data DOES NOT CONTAIN specified string "-SAD-"

==> D:\bat\SO\39359057.bat %computername%

`findstr` approach:
`Hostname` data CONTAINS specified string "myNewPC"

`substring` approach:
`Hostname` data CONTAINS specified string "myNewPC"

==>
```

Comment: Thank you for your information. It explains why I was always getting the same return value. I am assuming that I could just adjust the line to search for domain. How would I proceed with getting the script to fail with exit code if it finds that string or continue with removing profiles if it does not. My main concern is to have the script quit/cancel/stop if it finds that name and or domain. I want the box to just close. Thank you for your help.